# IdentityServer 4 Table Values

Tags: identityserver4

I just started working on a project using Identity Server 4. I have Googled and found a good deal of information. What I can't find is a list of values for certain columns. For example, I found that RefreshTokenExpiration can be either Absolute or Sliding. But the column type is int. That seems to be the case for other Tables/Columns as well. Do you know where I can find the list of values for these and other columns?

Comment: Did you check [IdentityServer documentation](https://identityserver4.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/client.html#token) ?

Comment: All the code is on github so you can just look at what the enums are for the EF model classes.

Comment: Thanks. That is what I needed. I was focused some much on the documentation I disregarded that. How do I make your reply as the answer?